# Set UserTokenProvider In .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, provider, data-protection

I am converting an existing Mvc application into .Net Core, The issue is to initialize

> **DataProtectorTokenProvider**

In Mvc application it belongs to

> **Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.IDataProtector**

Below code is used to generate **UserTokenProvider** in Mvc

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
}

public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new MySqlUserStore<ApplicationUser>());
    //var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        // RequireUniqueEmail = false
    };

    // Configure validation logic for passwords
    manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
    {
        RequiredLength = 2,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
        RequireDigit = false,
        RequireLowercase = false,
        RequireUppercase = false
    };

    // Configure user lockout defaults
    manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
    manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50);
    manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

    // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
    // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
    {
        MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
    });
    manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
    {
        Subject = "Security Code",
        BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
    });
    manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
    manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
    var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
    if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
    {
        manager.UserTokenProvider = 
            new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
    }
    return manager;
}
```

this auto initialize the **DataProtectorTokenProvider**

[image]

[image]
but In .Net Core Owin is no longer being used.

Now please let me know how can I initialize

> **UserTokenProvider**

in .net Core without using Owin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [TokenOptions.ProviderMap Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.tokenoptions.providermap?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and use your own TokenProvider and register it like so.

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options => {
options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("ASP.NET Identity", new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(MyTokenProvider)));
})
.AddTokenProvider<MyTokenProvider>(nameof(MyTokenProvider));
```

And the optional configuration in ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
    {
        o.Name = "ASP.NET Identity";
        o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    });
```

Check [this thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1018) for more info:

However [someone also commented](https://mattferderer.com/NotSupportedException-No-IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider-tuser-named-default-registered) out that adding the *.AddDefaultTokenProviders()* also might solve the issue so you can try that first.

```
 services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: hi could you tell me he content of MyTokenProvider?